# SQLite Today_date - date

Tags: android, date, android-sqlite

Good day!
I've got a problem of counting the date. I have one date (the number of a day in the year) and today's date. I need to get the result of subtraction (Today_date - COLUMN_DATE  = COLUMN_LAST)
Here's my code. Obviously, it contains some mistakes.

```
    Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Cursor cursor = mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_DATE} , null, null, null, null, null);
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_LAST, localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE) ));
    mDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, COLUMN_ID + " = " + cursor.getPosition(), null);
}
```

What should I do this thing to work? Thank's for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming that cursor position is equal to row id, it may not be true. When you're updating row you should pass column_id not cursor position.

```
    Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Cursor cursor = mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_DATE} , null, null, null, null, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        int columnId = cursor.getInt(0); // cause COLUMN_ID is 0th in projection above
        cv.put(COLUMN_LAST, localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - cursor.getInt(1));
        mDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, COLUMN_ID + " = ?" + id, new String[] {columnId});
    }

    // always close cursor
    cursor.close(); // you can use try-finally block
```

Comment: Aha, that's right, thank you :) Could you please give some comments about this code
`mDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, COLUMN_ID + " = ?" + id, new String[] {columnId});` How to get the id?

Comment: Simply question mark from COLUMN_ID + " = ?" is replaced by first value from string array. You can check docs for more explanation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: Hm... error. I've done that: `mDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, COLUMN_ID + " = ?" + columnId, new String[] {String.valueOf(columnId)});` Can it cause that error?

Comment: Yep, you should do `mDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, COLUMN_ID + " = " + columnId, null);` or `mDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
new String[] {String.valueOf(columnId)});`
Do you understand the difference ?

Comment: Oh, yes, silly mistake. Arguments are after comma! I like the first piece more. And... error. I have no idea why it appears, because I understand now each string.

Comment: Just that the application had stopped. No more info.

Comment: I've done debug and it's falling on that string: `mDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, COLUMN_ID + " = " + columnId, null);` These operations are placed in "open" function, which is called when activity creates the first time.

Comment: Don't perform db operations on main thread. Use AsyncTask or service instead.